# With C++ concurrency, do I need to use mutual exclusion?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have to design an app that reads UDP data off the local net and stores the data in a Current Value Table (CVT).

Then, a separate thread will come along and read the values out of the CVT, massage them, and send them out over UDP. CVT entries will consist of individual scalars like floats and ints.

My question is, how much mutual exclusion do I need to protect updating/reading from the CVT?

Put another way, if I have a thread writing to an 32bit int and another thread reading from that int, do I need to employ a mutex for it?

I don't care if the reader thread doesn't get the absolute latest value stored, I'm just concerned about trying to read that location WHILE it is being changed. I know the keyword "volatile" has uses for this scenario in Java, but it doesn't do the same thing in C++.

Comment: "I know the keyword "volatile" has uses for this scenario in Java, but it doesn't do the same thing in C++." Thank you. `_o/\_`

Comment: @GManNickG Would you welcome Captain Obvious on the stage?

Comment: @DesmondHume Don't drag me into this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot here depends on what sort of platform you're using to support the threading. If you have atomic types available, you can just use those. Otherwise, yes, you're pretty much stuck with a mutex (of some sort -- many platforms have more than one type).

Comment: Interesting. Please elaborate on "atomic types". A byte? The platform is just a 64 bit flavor of Windows 7. Could also be 32 bit XP and some point, I guess. Seems to me that a float or int or double would not be modified in memory atomically.

Comment: On an Intel x86 processor, reads and writes of 32-bit objects with 32-bit alignment are atomic. C++11 also adds an `atomic` class that includes atomic loads and stores. If your compiler supports it, I'd generally prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

As you describe this problem, it is already threadsafe provided you have only one writer (assuming the code runs on a 32-bit or higher word-width processor - in which case the 32-bit write is atomic).

The `volatile` storage modifier tells the compiler that a variable has non-standard load-store semantics - namely that it can't rely on a copy in CPU register remaining consistent with the value in memory.
The general side effect is to disable any optimizations around that variable (ie. ones that rely on the storage in memory not changing beneath it).  The result is a reload from memory on each use.

This is one of the few occasions where `volatile` is of use in a multi-threading situation.

Comment: `volatile` says that reads and writes of a variable are observable behavior, nothing more and nothing less (save compiler-specific extensions). It doesn't provide memory barriers and doesn't prevent CPU reordering. If it did, C++11 wouldn't have added `std::atomic<>`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are using for your current value table.  If you're using a database like SQLServer, then you shouldn't have any worries because the database will handle it.

If you're using the file system, then your problem remains.

You could write a TCP based Client/Server that queues requests and responds to them in sequential order.

If you're using memory then you'll need to use a mutex.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the question that the CVT is (and needs to be) in-memory

Comment: The question appears to have been edited, it wasn't obvious (to me at least) in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your 32 bit `int` is properly aligned in memory, and I'm guessing that it is because it's by default on most modern platforms, reading that `int` is practically thread-safe.

Comment: There are some (almost entirely theoretical, and most likely contrived) edge cases in which the compiler could do a CSE optimisation on the read of the current value. It gets even more fruity if you have concerns about the order in which writes to the table complete with respect to each other on SMP systems.

Comment: Just because an `int` is aligned doesn't mean it's thread-safe (has the necessary memory barriers and no data races).

Comment: @GManNickG Did you mean "race conditions" instead of "data races"?

Comment: @DesmondHume: No. Consider one thread does `i += 7;` while another does `i += 8`. If the compiler loads `i` into a register, adds to the register, then stores it into `i`, it could result in 7, 8 or 15. And without memory barriers, you aren't guaranteed that the write is visible to the reading thread, either because of reordering or because of cache incoherence. OP hasn't posted his platform yet, but there's no reason to hope for the best when you can just use the correct tools and guarantee it.

Comment: @GManNickG Try reading the question again. The OP said "I don't care if the reader thread doesn't get the absolute latest value stored, I'm just concernewd about trying to read that location WHILE it is being changed." All he needs is _some_ valid value. It could have just been updated, or be in the process of an update by another thread, the OP  _does not care_. An _approximate_ value would do just fine for him. He was worried about a situation when one thread tries to read the `int` value while bytes of the value are updated only partially, which should't happen to aligned data on practice.

Comment: @DesmondHume: That's fine, but it only addresses half the problem, the other half being reordering.